# Random forest like procedure for regression or other statistical models

Tags: regression, feature-selection, algorithms, random-forest, mathematical-statistics

I'm wondering if there exist methods similar to one used in random forest algorithm - I mean taking simultaneously bootstrap sample and random subset of features, then building statistisal model. Have anyone took this approach for building set of regression models ? Is this approach ( random subsample plus random subset of features ) somehow universal ?

Edition :
the question is all about the possibility of putting some other model in the place of classification tree in random forest, what is left is some kind of meta-algorithm (as bagging can be view as meta-algorithm) = bagging + random subsets of variables

Comment: You can use random forest for regression - if by regression you mean a continuous target.

Comment: What you are probably looking for is known as random subspaces (RS). This is the universal approach that has been published even before the random forest (RF). However, RF proposed using out of the bag samples for building the ensemble.

Comment: @B_Miner yes I know it, the question is all about the possibility of putting some other model in the place of classification tree in random forest

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is known as "bagging", a portmanteau of "boostrap aggregation". Indeed, the Random Forest algorithm is sometimes referred to as the bagged trees algorithm. There are various implementations of this, for instance the R library CARET provides a framework for creating bagging models from any base model of your choice (such as SVM, logistic regression or whatever else you like).

Comment: but bagging is only about sampling from training set but not from the set of variables

Comment: That's not the use of the term that I've encountered, which includes R packages for bagging and the journal articles written by the bagging method pioneer Leo Brieman. I'm sure people have done bagging without taking sub-samples of the variables, however the term refers in general to methods that take random samples of the training set and predictors, at least in my experience. Again I'd point out that the RF algorithm is also known as 'Bagged Trees' and this certainly includes, in general, sampling the variables.